# Certificate address mismatch warning GPO cannot be Disabled

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, certificate, internet-explorer

I found the "Turn on certificate address mismatch warning" and I need to set it to Disabled. Seems like the Console is not accepting that option (I Can set it to enabled and it will work) and I'd like to know if it is like that by design or if there is somehow another setting which is overriding mine. Thank you.

Comment: Please explain "Seems like the Console is not accepting that option". Do you get an error prompt? Client-side execution failures? Just no effect?

Comment: Simply no effect at all, when you open it again it looks the same as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through [`inetres.admx`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37009), the "Turn on certificate address mismatch warning" doesn't seem to have any value for the "Disabled" setting, but simply enforces it regardless local settings in IE when set to "Enabled".

To remove the setting on client computers, go for a Registry Group Policy Preference item, with the following properties:

**Action:** Update

**Hive:** HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
**Key Path:** *Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings*
**Value name:** `WarnOnBadCertRecving`
**Value type:** `DWORD`
**Value data:** `0x0`

Be aware that it only works for IE 8+

Answer (score 1):

You should also realise the danger in this. If you're using a self signed cert and don't like the error, it's much better to get the certificate installed onto the client machines. You're opening your users up to very simple MITM attacks, plus this setting is browser dependant so has limited reach.

Comment: Certificates from untrusted CA's will still result in warnings, but it *does* leave you vulnerable to MITM attacks through DNS poisoning etc

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Absolutely correct - I wasn't doing enough thinking!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work on HKLM, has to be on the user's profile.  The check will go away, but it still doesn't work.  Try going to any banking site if you have the issue.  The below is the only way to get rid of the error.  Can be done in GP preferences is your users are a member of the forest.

Put it somewhere like all users startup or USRLOGIN.CMD

reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /V "WarnonBadCertRecving" /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f